# Need help translating a Excel formula to R function - Looping / iterating to build a matrix

Tags: r, excel, excel-formula, matrix-multiplication

I have built this Excel formula, which takes values and builds a new matrix out of it.

However I am working in R and it's not very convenient to update the spreadsheet in Excel and import it into R later on.

My working excel code:

```
=IF(AND($A8=H$2;H$10>0;$I8>0;$I8>H$10);1;IF(AND($A8<>H$2;H$10>0;$I8>0;MAXIFS($I:$I;$A:$A;$A8)=$I8;MAXIFS($10:$10;$2:$2;H$2)=H$10;$I8>=MAXIFS($10:$10;$2:$2;H$2));1;0))
```

This is how a sample of my dataset looks like:

[image]

I have X groups (orange) and Y different items (green) with all one distinct value (blue).

A first step would be to just implement this formula in R.

A second would be, since I have several columns, to have an automatic for loop implemented that adds up to a *final* matrix that I need.

Any help appreciated!

head of my df (group = orange groups, Name = green, col_X = the values (blue) - in my excel example it's just one column).

```
 ID group Name col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7
1  1    X1    a     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2  2    X1    b     0     0     0     3     0     0     0
3  3    X2    c     3     0     0     0     0     2     0
4  4    X2    d     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
5  5    Y3    e     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6  6    X1    f     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Please include the headers so that it can be possible to navigate and design the formula!

Comment: I have added the header, hope that helps?

Comment: While what you added is good, I think the "headers" request was so that we know what (e.g.) `$A8=H$2` is referring to, and which cell contains that example formula you provided. So please update your image to include the row and column names from Excel, or clearly identify at least one of the cells.

Comment: There is no row 10 in your Excel example, regularly called in formula. And what cell does that formula reside? Also, R matrices does not support multiple headers. Please describe with actual relationship of variables what you are trying to do.

Comment: @r2evans Oh, I got you and updated the headers!

Comment: @Parfait Yes, I have just seen that I dropped the whole example by one row, it should be more clear now. I basically nee a new matrix for every column and they all add up to one _final_ matrix, if that's what you asked for?

Comment: You should explain in words what you are trying to do. Many R users (including me) don't have any desire to try and understand Excel formulas.

Comment: Ok, say we only look at col_1 first. I am building a matrix that takes the value from *a* (vertical) and checks whether it is smaller or bigger than the value coming from horizontal. Example from the screenshot: small *a* (5) is bigger than small *b* ( 4) -> 1 in the matrix. But there’s a catch: I have capital letter *A* groups that go always 0 between groups except when the biggest value from two different groups meet (Example from Excel *Aa* and *Bc* or *Ce*.

Comment: @Roland the Excel in words: if group 1 and group 2 are the same then check if the values in row and col are greater than 0 and check if the row value is greater than the col value - if those specifications are true -> 1. Else if the groups 1 and 2 are **not** the same: check if the row and col value are greater 0 and check if the row value is the maximum value of it's group and check if the col value are the maximum of it's group - if true than compare both and if the row value is greater or equal to the col value -> 1 ELSE 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets a lot easier if you think about this in "tidy long data format" instead of "matrix wide data format". If you use `expand.grid(ColB=letters[1:6], Row3=letters[1:6])` you get all 36 combinations of `a` to `f` lower case letters, and from that you can make all calculations. The following code will return your intended outcome:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

base <- data.frame(
  lowerletter=letters[1:6],
  upperletter=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
  number=c(5, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4)
)

df <- expand.grid(ColB=letters[1:6], Row3=letters[1:6]) %>%
  left_join(rename(base, ColB=lowerletter), by='ColB') %>%
  left_join(rename(base, Row3=lowerletter), by='Row3') %>%
  rename(
    ColA=upperletter.x,
    ColI=number.x,
    Row2=upperletter.y,
    Row10=number.y
  )

df <- df %>%
  group_by(ColA) %>%
  mutate(maxIbyA=max(ColI)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Row2) %>%
  mutate(max10by2=max(Row10)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    z = case_when(
      (ColA==Row2) & (Row10>0) & (ColI>Row10) ~ 1,
      (ColA!=Row2) & (Row10>0) & (ColI>0) & (maxIbyA==ColI) & (max10by2==Row10) & (ColI >= max10by2) ~ 1,
      TRUE~0
    )
  )

df %>%
  mutate(
    Col=paste(Row2, Row3, Row10, sep='_'),
    Row=paste(ColA, ColB, ColI)
  ) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols='Row', names_from='Col', values_from='z')
```

will output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Row   A_a_5 A_b_4 B_c_3 B_d_1 C_e_5 C_f_4
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A a 5     0     1     1     0     1     0
2 A b 4     0     0     0     0     0     0
3 B c 3     0     0     0     1     0     0
4 B d 1     0     0     0     0     0     0
5 C e 5     1     0     1     0     0     1
6 C f 4     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

to apply this logic at the same time to multiple columns, you can turn your original data frame to long format, add the column name to the `expand.grid` like `expand.grid(ColB=unique(base$Name), Row3=unique(base$Name), col=unique(base$col))`, and include the column to the `group_by` used to calculate the `max` values.

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID=1:6,
  group=c('X1', 'X2', 'X2', 'X2', 'Y2', 'X1'),
  Name=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),
  col_1=c(0,0,3,0,0,0),
  col_2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
  col_3=c(0,0,0,0,0,1),
  col_4=c(0,3,0,0,0,0),
  col_5=c(0,0,0,1,0,1),
  col_6=c(0,0,2,0,0,0),
  col_7=c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
)

base <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=starts_with('col_'), names_to='col') %>%
  select(group, Name, value, col)


df2 <- expand.grid(ColB=unique(base$Name), Row3=unique(base$Name), col=unique(base$col)) %>%
  left_join(rename(base, ColB=Name), by=c('ColB', 'col')) %>%
  left_join(rename(base, Row3=Name), by=c('Row3', 'col')) %>%
  rename(
    ColA=group.x,
    ColI=value.x,
    Row2=group.y,
    Row10=value.y
  ) %>%
  group_by(col, ColA) %>%
  mutate(maxIbyA=max(ColI, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(col, Row2) %>%
  mutate(max10by2=max(Row10, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    z = case_when(
      (ColA==Row2) & (Row10>0) & (ColI>Row10) ~ 1,
      (ColA!=Row2) & (Row10>0) & (ColI>0) & (maxIbyA==ColI) & (max10by2==Row10) & (ColI >= max10by2) ~ 1,
      TRUE~0
    )
  )
```

then you can just filter whatever original column you are interested and it will output the matrix:

```
df2 %>%
  filter(col == 'col_5') %>%
  mutate(
    Col=paste(Row2, Row3, Row10, sep='_'),
    Row=paste(ColA, ColB, ColI)
  ) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols='Row', names_from='Col', values_from='z')
```

which would output:

```
  Row    X1_a_0 X2_b_0 X2_c_0 X2_d_1 Y2_e_0 X1_f_1
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 X1 a 0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2 X2 b 0      0      0      0      0      0      0
3 X2 c 0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4 X2 d 1      0      0      0      0      0      1
5 Y2 e 0      0      0      0      0      0      0
6 X1 f 1      0      0      0      1      0      0
```

Comment: Perfect! And so easy and clean! What I am wondering now. How can I automatically iterate over several columns that have data and add this all up to one final matrix that looks like your outpot? In example I have printed the head of my df.

Comment: Please see my edit. You don't need to iterate, you can do it all at once if you turn your original dataframe to long format and each column becames a column-value pair.

Comment: @Daniel_R thanks so far!! How can I automatically add up X amount of columns to my final output? Say Col_1:Col_3?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you meant, but `for (i in 1:3) { df[paste0("Col_", i)] <- "something" }` will add 3 columns and you can replace `1:3` for `1:x` if `x` is any integer.

Comment: `df2 %>%
  filter(col == 'col_5')` <- this let's me filter individually. However how can I summarise instead of filter? eg. col_2+col_5, so each value is a summary from all the other matrices? That's my last question and I am very thankful so far! THANKS!

Comment: You can use every dataframe operations to df2, including summarise: `df2 %>% group_by(Row2, Row3, ColA, ColB) %>% summarise(z=sum(z))`

Comment: Hey, so I found a little mistake. When I try to output one col, say col_1, it returns me the max for B over all columns, which is obviously not right - therefor it only turns 1 like once. Any workaround? Or do I have to feed all the columns individually into the matrix-builder and then add up them all together?

Comment: You must make sure you include the column in the grouping, replacing `group_by(ColA)` for `group_by(col, ColA)` before calculating the max with `mutate(maxIbyA=max(ColI))`